# JWPlayer rtmp redirect from php

Tags: jwplayer, jwplayer6

I want to redirect dynamically to a file based on where the file requested exists. this is my PHP file code (simplified)

```
<?php
    header('Location:rtmp://192.168.112.128/vod/got.mp4');
    exit();
?>
```

JS code

```
jwplayer("myElement").setup({
    width: "90%",
    aspectratio: "16:9",
    autostart: true,
    skin: "bekle",
    file: "http://192.168.112.128/redirect.php",
    type: "mp4",
});
```

JWPlayer throws an error `Error load media: File could not be player`. Is it even possible to redirect to rtmp streams dynamically ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution was to use smil. just echo these line from php file

```
<smil>
  <head>
    <meta base="rtmp://192.168.112.128/vod/"/>
  </head>
  <body>
     <video src="got.mp4"/>
  </body>
</smil>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
type: "mp4",
```

To:

```
type: "rtmp",
```

Comment: now it's throwing `Error loading stream: Manifest not found or invalid`, i checked JWplayer site it says crossdomain might be an issue, But that's not the case.

Comment: I am using NGINX + RTMP-HLS-Module.

Comment: Do you have a link we can look at? Perhaps you are not forming the RTMP URL correctly?

Comment: I have sent a link via email support from JWPlayer site.